# What is the equivalent of oracle VARRAY in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

What is the equivalent of oracle varray in postgres.
Code :

```
TYPE xxx is varray(2000) of gt_name%rowtype .
```

gt_name is a cursor name.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in PostgreSQL is an array.  Figure out what data type `gt_name` is. if that is (for example), `text`, then you'd use the type `text[]`.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) for details.

Comment: Gt_name is a cursor .and gt_name%rowtype declare a cursor variable

Comment: @Ananthurajeev Yes.